# Do there exist uniform triangular prisms with all vertices in $\mathbb Z^3$?

Tags: geometry, polyhedra, polytopes

It's quite easy to find a regular square prism (cube) or a regular triangular antiprism (octahedron) with vertices in $\mathbb Z^3$. Take for instance, take the convex hulls $$ \begin{align*}
&\operatorname{hull}(\{(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,1,0),(0,1,1),(1,0,0),(1,0,1),(1,1,0),(1,1,1)\}), \text{ and}
\\
&\operatorname{hull}(\{(0,0,1),(0,1,0),(1,0,0),(0,0,-1),(0,-1,0),(-1,0,0)\})
\end{align*}
$$
respectively.

For a much more interesting example of embedding the cube, see [Table 1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.4569.pdf) from Ionascu and Obando: $$
\operatorname{hull}(\{(0, 3, 2), (1, 1, 4), (2, 2, 0), (2, 5, 3), (3, 0, 2), (3, 3, 5), (4,4, 1), (5, 2, 3)\}).
$$

[image]
[image]

#### Question

Do there exist [uniform triangular prisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_prism#As_a_semiregular_(or_uniform)_polyhedron) with all vertices in $\mathbb Z^3$ (equivalently $\mathbb Q^3$)?
If not, can it be done in $\mathbb Z^4$, $\mathbb Z^5$, etc?

(I've checked all examples in $\mathbb Z^3$ where the triangular faces have side lengths up to $\sqrt{700}$. This did not produce any examples, but there are plenty of near-misses.)

Comment: I hesitate to write an answer again (because it seems rocky and ugly, so I might wait a little longer to try to tidy it up), but you can be sure that there isn't such thing in $\mathbb{Z}^3$, I've checked. This time correctly :D

Comment: I instantly thought of this: $$ \begin{align} & (1,0,0),\quad(0,1,0),\quad(0,0,1) \\ {} \\ & (2,1,1), \quad (1,2,1), \quad (1,1,2) & & \phantom{mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm}  \end{align} $$ But of course that doesn't work. $\qquad$

Comment: That this is possible in sufficiently large dimension follows more generally from the answers to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/385361/108884).

Comment: @M.Winter: I think it actually does work - the post relies on a rational *squared* distance, which is true of the distance between any two points in $\mathbb{Q}^n$, so things should be OK.

Comment: @RavenclawPrefect Shame on me. This was my own question and I forgot how to apply it. You are right of course.

Comment: In $\mathbb{Z}^4$, there is no solution too.

Comment: @donaastor How do you know?

Comment: @M.Winter I found a proof of course. I will write an answer as soon as I get to a computer.

Comment: @donaastor: Do you have a writeup of the $\mathbb{Z}^4$ case? I'd love to see a proof, or at least a sketch of your approach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose that there exists a triangular prism in $\mathbb{Z}^3$ of side length $s$. From a given vertex $V$, let $a$ and $b$ be the vectors on the triangular face containing $V$ and $c$ the vector from $V$ to its pair on the other triangular face. Note that $a,b$, and $c$ are all of length $s$.

[image]

Now, consider the integer vector $a\times b$; since $a$ and $b$ are $60^\circ$ apart, it has length $s^2\cdot\frac{\sqrt{3}}2$. Up to a change of sign, this vector is parallel to $c$, so $c$ is a rational multiple of $a\times b$ (since both lie in $\mathbb{Z}^3$). Thus, $s$ and $\frac{s^2\sqrt{3}}2$ differ by a rational factor, so we conclude that $s$ is a rational multiple of $\sqrt{3}$.

This means that we can scale the prism so that its side length is an integer multiple of $\sqrt{3}$. Then scale it by a further factor of $2$, so that the midpoints of each edge also have integer coordinates. Let $k\sqrt{3}$ be the integer distance from a vertex to a midpoint of an edge.

But now consider the integer vector from the midpoint of a non-triangle edge to a non-adjacent vertex: it has length $(k\sqrt{3})\cdot \sqrt{5}$.

So, the squared distance $15k^2$ between these two integer points is the sum of three squares. Note that $k^2$ is of the form $4^n(8a+1)$, so $15k^2$ is of the form $4^n(8b+7)$. But, by [Legendre's three-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem), such integers are not expressible as the sum of three squares! So no such prism exists.

---

There do exist triangular prisms in $\mathbb{Z}^5$: Take the first three coordinates to be any permutation of $(0,0,1)$, and the last two to be either $(0,0)$ or $(1,1)$. This gives a triangular prism of side length $\sqrt{2}$.

I'm not sure yet about $\mathbb{Z}^4$ - my guess is no, but checking some small examples seems worthwhile.

Comment: Your example for $\mathbb{Z}^5$ is very nice